# What hit dice do sages use?

Tags: dnd-5e, class, hit-dice

I'm creating a character for DnD 5e, and I was wondering what kind of hit dice Sages use. He's a Wizard's Apprentice if that helps.

Comment: There is no officially published "Sage" class, can you give a source for the class?

Comment: *Sage* is a possible background not a class. Or are you writing a *Sage* class and ask for home-brew advice?

Comment: In what language do you read the rules?

Comment: oooooooohhhhhhhh I realised my mistake

Answer (score 2):

There is two different associations with hit dice:

1: Class. Wizards have a D6 hit die, Fighters have a D10, Barbarians have a D12, and so on. This is the one player characters use, but isn't used that commonly for NPC's/

2: Size. Most NPC's have hit dice dependent on their size. Tiny have a D4, Small have a D6, Medium have a D8, and so on. If you are building an NPC, this is how you determine their hit dice.

There is a Apprentice Wizard NPC in VGTM, if you are looking for a stat block as a DM. As a player, your hit die is dependent on your class. Sage is a background.